# C# DateTime parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

My problem is I have to parse a date in the format

```
Tue Oct 8 05:45 GMT
```

but what I always get using DateTime.parse() is:

```
system.formatexception the datetime represented by the string is not supported in calendar system.globalization.gregoriancalendar
```

how can this issue can be resolved?

Comment: How are you calling `DateTime.Parse()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string format = "ddd MMM d hh:mm 'GMT'";
dateString = "Tue Oct 8 05:45 GMT";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

try 
{
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
}
catch (FormatException) 
{
    // Date does not conform to format defined
}
```

If the need for a `try-catch` causes you heartburn, then you can use `TryParseExact()`, like this:

```
string format = "ddd MMM d hh:mm 'GMT'";
dateString = "Tue Oct 8 05:45 GMT";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, 
                           out dateValue))
{
    // Date conforms to format defined and result is in dateValue variable
}
else
{
    // Date does not conform to format defined
}
```

Comment: Since the date string includes "GMT", consider using `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` instead of `DateTimeStyles.None`.